How to show that $M$ is not finitely axiomatizable in the following case?

Problem: A set of formulas $M_0$ is an axiom system for a set of formulas $M$ if $\{A |A \text{ is a model for }M_0\} = \{A |A \text{ is a model for }M\}$, where $A$ is an assignment, or valuation. $M$ is called finitely axiomatizable if $M$ has a finite axiom system. Suppose $\{F_1, F_2, F_3, ...\}$ is an axiom system for a set $M$ where for all $n \geq 1$,
$$\models(F_{n + 1} \rightarrow F_n) \text{ and } \not\models (F_n \rightarrow F_{n + 1}).$$
Show that $M$ is not finitely axiomatizable.

This is a somewhat tricky problem I met as an exercise in Uwe Schoning's Logic for Computer Scientists. Someone has asked the question on Chegg before but the answer there seems to be a little incomplete.
I've been thinking of using proof by contradiction, but don't really know what the details are. Could someone offer some hints or a solution to this problem?

This is a consequence of the compactness theorem. Suppose $\{G\}$ were an axiomatization of $\{F_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (we can always conjoin finitely many sentences, so a finite axiomatization exists iff a single-sentence axiomatization exists). We then get $$\{F_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\models G,$$ so by compactness we have in fact $$\{F_1,F_2,...,F_n\}\models G$$ for some $n$. But since each $F_i$ implies the previous one this means $$F_n\models G$$ which is a contradiction since

 we also have $G\models F_{n+1}$ and by assumption $F_n\not\models F_{n+1}$.

Note that the only thing we used here about the logic we're working with is that it is compact. So this strategy would apply to first-order logic, propositional logic, and some weirder logics besides. (In particular, I haven't even used the deduction theorem: since everything here is about $\models$, we're allowed to freely switch between e.g. "$\models F_{i+1}\rightarrow F_i$" and "$F_{i+1}\models F_i$" simply because of the $\rightarrow$-clause in the definition of the satisfaction relation.)

Just to make sure I am clear about the notation: is $A$ here an assignment (or valuation)?

@The_Eureka No, a sentence; I didn't notice you'd used $A$ for an assignment. I'll change my notation.

Oh, alright. Thanks for your response anyway.

But now I seem to have spotted another question. The compactness theorem states that "A set $M$ of formulas is satisfiable iff every finite subset of $M$ is satisfiable." But does this necessarily mean that if  ${F_i : i \in \mathbb{N}} \models G$, then ${F_1, F_2, \dots, F_n} \models G$, as the subset of formulas ${F_1, F_2, \dots, F_n}$ might be satisfied by another $G$? Or is there something I've missed?

@The_Eureka Yes, it does. This is a standard corollary of compactness (or already part of compactness itself, there are a few ways to state the compactness theorem), and it's a good exercise. (HINT: think about ${\neg G, F_1, F_2, F_3, ...}$.)

Interesting corollary! Then this seems to solve the problem clearly. I'll try to prove the corollary.
